# Firestore Database Registration Failed Permission Denied But Actually Successfully Registers

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, nosql

So I am having a rather ambiguous issue with my database. Everything was working fine and anytime I would register or somebody would register on my app, it would make the messasge "Registration Successful!" pop up.

I have been updating my code daily and working on changing things in the app and around the database. Today while registering a test user, I got this message - [image: this message popped up]

It claims that registration failed, but the account was successfully registered. And I have tested this with 3 more accounts. Same message - registration, however, is actually successful and the user can log in with his details.

I have not coded this exception. I have coded exceptions such as password too short, registration failed, no internet, etc, but never have I created a Permission check. I think the Permission Denied comes from the +e.getMessage()? Could I have changed something inside the firestorm database rules?

This is my code:

```
    private void showREGISTERnew() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("REGISTER");
    dialog.setMessage("Please use email to register.");


    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View layout_login = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_login, null);

    final MaterialEditText editEmail = layout_login.findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    final MaterialEditText editPassword = layout_login.findViewById(R.id.editPassword);


    dialog.setView(layout_login);

    //set btton

    dialog.setPositiveButton("REGISTER", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            //check validation

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editEmail.getText().toString())){
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter email address", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return;
            }



            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editPassword.getText().toString())){
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter your password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return;
            }

            if(editPassword.getText().toString().length() < 6){
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Password too short.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return;
            }



            //reg new user

            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(editEmail.getText().toString(), editPassword.getText().toString())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                            //save user to db
                            User user = new User();
                            user.setEmail(editEmail.getText().toString());

                            //user setphone
                            //user setname

                            user.setPassword(editPassword.getText().toString());
                            //use email to key
                            users.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "You have registered successfully.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Registration failed."+e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                        }
                                    });

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Registration failed."+e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually implemented two databases. One that will hold the userbase ad one that will hold price and location data.

However, I forgot that after a certain period of time, read and write permissions will be automatically set to false.

When I got the notification weeks ago, I changed back the read and write permissions to true on the main database, but forgot about the second one.

I checked the second one and the permissions were set to false, thus giving me registration failed, permission denied even though I could register.

After changing them back to true, application works flawlessly.